# jQuery getting array of form params and submitting in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a form submit, I'm looking to append data from a different form and submit that and the original form data via an ajax request.

The form fields I'm looking to gain are in the following format:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selected[84334][]" value="865804">
<input type="hidden" name="selected[54434][]" value="865807">
<input type="hidden" name="selected[54494][]" value="865808">
<input type="hidden" name="selected[54494][]" value="866212">
```

and the ajax request that I currently have is:

```
var form_data = $(this).serializeArray();
var more_data = $('input[name="data[]"]', '.fields_container_class').serializeArray();
var data = $.merge( form_data, more_data );

$.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  type: $(this).attr('method'),
  data: $.param(data)
});
```

I've been able to capture the data in the hidden fields with the name of 'data[]', but how can I capture and include the 'selected[][]' fields, but maintain the keys?

Thanks for your help

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the `selected[X][]` fields you can use the 'attribute begins with' selector, like this:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serializeArray();
  var more_data = $('input[name="data[]"]', '.fields_container_class').serializeArray();
  var even_more_data = $('input[name^="selected"]', '.fields_container_class').serializeArray();
  
  var data = form_data.concat(more_data, even_more_data);
  console.log(data);
  
  // AJAX call...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fields_container_class">
  <input type="hidden" name="data[]" value="lorem">
  <input type="hidden" name="data[]" value="ipsum">
  
  <input type="hidden" name="selected[84334][]" value="865804">
  <input type="hidden" name="selected[54434][]" value="865807">
  <input type="hidden" name="selected[54494][]" value="865808">
  <input type="hidden" name="selected[54494][]" value="866212">

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="foo" value="foobar" />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note the use of `concat()` here instead of jQuery's `$.merge()`. This is because the former allows you to concatenate multiple arrays in one call, the latter does not.

Finally, to simplify the logic you can use the spread operator, `...`, to merge the arrays at the point of declaration. Beware this is unsupported in IE, though.

```
var data = [
  ...$(this).serializeArray(),
  ...$('input[name="data[]"]', '.fields_container_class').serializeArray(),
  ...$('input[name^="selected"]', '.fields_container_class').serializeArray()
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^`. The `[attribute^=value]` selector matches every element whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

See the code below:

```js
var data = $('input[name^="selected"]').serializeArray();

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="selected[84334][]" value="865804">
<input type="hidden" name="selected[54434][]" value="865807">
<input type="hidden" name="selected[54494][]" value="865808">
<input type="hidden" name="selected[54494][]" value="866212">
```